# Disabling Email app

Tags: email

I set up the Android Email app on my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo because I thought I would move from Internet mail on Outlook.com to using Email. The app did not download all my mail but only downloads new mail, which I don't like. Besides, I am too used to using INternet for mail to think about using the Email app. However, the app is giving me annoying notifications all the time, and I definitely don't want to know every time a new email arrives. I prefer to see it on Internet. So how do I eliminate my account from Email? Or how do I turn off the notifications? Or how do I get to see all the mails I have on my Outlook account on the app instead of just the unread mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "get rid of it", try the following steps:

1. From the home-screen, open *Settings*
2. Navigate to *Apps*, tap the "All" tab
3. Scroll until you find the Email app. Tap it.
4. Tap the buttons to "Clear cache", "Delete data", "Force stop", and "Disable" (in this order)<sup>1</sup>

Now that app should no longer bother you. If you wish to use another Email app instead, there are plenty; you might e.g. wish to take a look at my list of [Email Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_emailapps) for a selection.

---

<sup>**1:** Depending on the ROM builder, you might not be able to disable the Email app. That would only leave rooted solutions for that final step.</sup>

Comment: As you foresaw, the Disable button was grayed out :). However the problem should be solved now @Izzy.

Comment: Glad to read! Mind to tell us how you've solved the "grayed-out button"?

Comment: I didn't :). As long as it doesn't annoy me, it can stay there, since I have enough memory to not care about it :). I won't take the trouble of rooting just for that.

Comment: Yepp, that explains :) Still, it's not only RAM. See my comment on [Trish's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/89747/16575): at least the "Exchange component" polls all 60s even with no account configured (noticed that on a freshly flashed device). That might wake-up your Droid and eat some juice, even if little. But again, if you've got no trouble with your "battery uptime", that won't bother you either ;)

Comment: And yet another grayed-out button for "Exchange Services" :). It is really astonishing how much stuff I _can't_ do :).

Comment: Going a little OT now (but it's related to the "gray buttons", so it should be fine): Many more good reasons to root. A device without root is a half device to me. See our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) and check the linked information as well. Again, I'm no missionary – if you're happy without, stay happy ;) For more, better move to our chat room :)

Answer (score 1):

**Turn off notifications:** (this is the same for all apps) **Settings >> Apps.** Slide to the "All" section and scroll down until you find "Email". Uncheck the box for "Show notifications". You should probably do the same for Exchange Services, which has the same icon.

**Remove account from Email app**: Settings > Scroll down to the Accounts and tap on Email. Tap the account you want to remove. Tap on the menu button on the upper right (three vertical square) and pick "Remove Account".

Comment: Good points, Trush! (+1 from me) To fully get rid of that crazy app, see my answer – and optionally apply the same steps to the "Exchange" app (which polls all 60s in the background even with no account configured and the Email app disabled).

Comment: @TrishLing the box is grayed out, and I see no "Email" under "Accounts".